# Integrating microsoft team with Custom app using custom bots

Tags: bots, cakephp-3.0, microsoft-teams

I 'm working on the integration of Microsoft Teams and the PHP client framework (which can save data in the database).

The app I built uses actionable messaging to do this. This app can't send any messages to endpoint from Bot.

Do I have to register the Bot somewhere? Is there a specific way it has to respond?

My pain point can be overcome by the outgoing webhooks but they are not scoped to personal level.

The link that I follow -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/create-messaging-extension#create-your-app-manifest-using-app-studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-nodejs-app-studio#download-and-host-your-app

What I have tried so far -

I tried a sample nodejs app that communicates with MS-Teams.

I tried to build an App with bot capabilities using AppStudio. I did, but it doesn't request my endpoint.

I described my usage scenario. Can you please suggest the way out that will help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're having a problem registering the bot *(correct me if i'm wrong)*.

I'm assuming your bot is working fine in [Bot Framework Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/blob/master/README.md)

There are certain steps you need to follow to register your bot before testing it out on MS Teams (or any other platform). I'll list the method which doesn't require an Azure subscription but you will need a Microsoft 365 Account (same account you're using for Teams). You can also have a look at all the exhaustive methods to deploy your bot [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams)

1. Expose your localhost as a web address (you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for this)
2. Go to [Dev Botframework- Register bot](https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new), sign in with your account and click on create a new bot. In the messaging endpoint paste your exposed bot endpoint and append it with /api/messages i.e https:4ety45.com/api/messages
3. You will get a Microsoft APP ID and Password, add it to your bots authentication/config (& manifest.json) file
4. Go to MS Teams, Appstudio and under Manifest Editor click on import existing app (if you already have the manifest.json file) else click on create a new app.
5. Make sure to fill out all the info and under bots sections, you should see your bot (add it if you don't) and make sure the messaging extensions are configured to your bot.
6. Click on test & distribute then install to test out the bot